# Wireguard: Access Raspberry Pi from Windows 10 through local network

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, vpn, wireguard

To preface, I am very much a noob when it comes to networking, so bear with me.

I am trying to access files on my Raspberry Pi from Windows 10. I will eventually have a system setup to automatically send files from the Pi to Windows without doing it manually. Both systems are using Mullvad VPN: Pi OS is set up through Wireguard and Windows is running the Mullvad client. The problem is, I am unable to connect to Pi OS on my local network when the Pi is running Wireguard. [Here is what the conf file for Wireguard looks like](https://pastebin.com/4S0CKGtN). Some things I have tried:

- Changed `AllowedIPS=0.0.0.0/0` to `AllowedIPS=192.168.x.x/24` ( local ip of Windows machine). Tested connection with ipleak.net and website reported actual ip and location.
- Changed `AllowedIPS` to `0.0.0.0/5, 8.0.0.0/7, 11.0.0.0/8, 12.0.0.0/6, 16.0.0.0/4` etc.... Could not access internet with this option.

How can I access my Pi OS using Windows on the same local network while also having the Pi always connected to Wireguard?

Comment: I wonder if having `8.8.8.8/32` in AllowedIPs is necessary, since that is covered by `8.0.0.0/7` - also `192.168.x.x/24` isn't valid, you need numbers there which you don't have to hide since they are, in the case of 192.168.0.0/16 subnet, not public

Comment: Yeah, I have my actual ip for the Windows machine in the conf without the x's.